# Overriding Text and OnKeyUp/OnKeyPress

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, overriding

I'm having a problem where I have created a custom control that inherits from TextBox where I need to override the `Text` property and the `OnKeyPress` or `OnKeyUp` event.

- The text property is being overriden to display a different value than the actual value of the text box (for unit conversions)
- The OnKeyPress/OnKeyUp I am currently trying to add to only allow for numerical values to be entered.

When the KeyPress event is triggered, the text that gets updated is `base.Text` instead of my override... any ideas on how I overcome this problem?

```
    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            displayValue = parse;
            base.Text = this.ContainsFocus ? displayValue.ToString() : displayValue.ToString("N3");
        }
    }
    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        if ((e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9) ||
            (e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9) ||
            e.KeyCode == Keys.Decimal)
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        //Code to only accept numerical buttons
        base.OnKeyUp(e);
    }
```

Comment: Do you set e.Handled = true; in OnKeyUp?

Comment: I set absolutely nothing in it at the minute, the only code that was in there was a load of `e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0` etc, EDIT: and the `base.OnKeyUp(e)` shown here

Comment: @AndreyVoloshin - I've updated my example to include my complete onkeyup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All it needed in the end was

```
protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
{....
    base.OnKeyPress(e);
    Text = base.Text;
 }
```

I realised the reason why this was the case is that base.OnKeyPress(e) must handle the base.Text which means that there would be no way for it to know about my override

Answer (score 1):

Try change your `OnKeyUp`:

```
 protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
    {       
        if ((e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9) ||
            (e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9) ||
            e.KeyCode == Keys.Decimal)
        {
             e.Handled = false;
             base.OnKeyUp(e);
        }
        else
        {
             e.Handled= true;
        }       

    }
```

**EDIT:** Use `KeyPress` instead:

```
 protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = false;
                base.OnKeyPress(e);
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to override AppendText property.

```
public void AppendText(string text)
    Member of System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase
```

Comment: Hi Andrey, the problem I'm having is not handling non-numerical characters but the fact that the event is calling `base.Text` instead of `override Text`

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```
  protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
             if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
                         && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
                    e.Handled = true;
            base.OnKeyPress(e);
         }
```